# UIView has different cornerRadius than CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rounded-corners, cashapelayer

I want to add a background view to a `UITableViewCell`, and also a `CAShapeLayer` to act as a border around the background view (I will need a dashed border).

My problem is however, even though I set the cornerRadius of the view and the layer to the same value, they render completely differently.

[image]

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

The code:

```
final class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    private let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let _backgroundView = UIView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Add a blue background view.
        contentView.insertSubview(_backgroundView, at: 0)
        _backgroundView.backgroundColor = .blue
        _backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 28

        // Add the border layer.
        borderLayer.fillColor = nil
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 2
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Update the frames.
        _backgroundView.frame = contentView.bounds
        borderLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: contentView.bounds, cornerRadius: _backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    }
}
```

[A Playground Gist to reproduce it](https://gist.github.com/vinczebalazs/83743f05ba028500c733be7830e23dda)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possibly the different corner algo for UIBezierPath - https://medium.com/fueled-engineering/continuous-rounded-corners-with-uikit-b575d50ab232

Comment: Border will show inside the rect  not outside the rect,  You need to add border value i.e 2 with  `borderLayer.path`

Comment: try something like           `let rect = contentView.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building the path from a CGPath directly seems to solve the problem.

```
borderLayer.path = CGPath(roundedRect: contentView.bounds, cornerWidth: _backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius,
                          cornerHeight: _backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius, transform:  nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the calculation of corner radius is not consistent to UIBezierPath(roundedRect:, cornerRadius:).

How about an alternative approach??

Like:

```
_backgroundView.layer.borderWidth = 2
_backgroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```